# Observable that would emit only when subscribed to

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I want to create an observable, that would emit items only when it has subscribers listening to it. The subscribers could be added and or disposed at any time, there could be a long delay when no subscribers are connected before new ones are connected again.
One of the possible ways I think could work is:

```
observable = Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<Long>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<Long> call() throws Exception {
            final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

            return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Long>() {

                @Override
                public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<Long> e) throws Exception {
                    emitter = e;
                }
            }).doOnSubscribe(new Consumer<Disposable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
                    counter.incrementAndGet();
                    startEmitting(emitter);
                }
            }).doOnDispose(new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    if (counter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                        stopEmitting(emitter);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This solution would probably work, however the Observable would never finish. Is that a problem?
Having it finished with the stopEmitting fuction, I guess I would have to create a new observer next time anybody wants to subscribe?
Also the way I need to pass an emitter to onSubscribe or onDispose functions feels strange and I wonder if it is thread safe?

Could anyone recommend a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about rx-java2 but I have a few recommendations to the observable pattern.

You could maybe create an Object with called ObservableEmitter. In this class you can create a method like this subscribe(Subscriber subscriber) and an method emit().

The Subscriber Interface is then implemented by your subscribers. I would call the method receive(Message message).

In code it would look like this:

```
public interface Subscriber {
  void receive(Message msg);
}

public class ObservableEmitter {
 private List<Subscriber> subscribers = new ArrayList<Subscriber>();
 public subscribe(Subscriber sub) {
  subscribers.add(sub);
 }
 public void emit(Message msg) {
   for(Subscriber sub : subscribers) {
     sub.receive(msg);
   }
 }
}
```

This way you would only emit a message if there is a subscriber. There is some code missing on your minimal example: startEmitting() and how you call observable

Comment: Hi Thomas, I think your solution would work with some synchronization on the array. However I am keen for an rx solution to be able to use the easier threading and the ability to mix and transform the streams in the subscribers.
startEmitting is just to say this is where I would start/stop emitting the stuff needed to the emitter...